# Can you explain how this answer is correct?

Tags: python, list, max, min

```
a = [1, 5, 8]
b = [2, 6, 9, 10]
c = [100, 200]

print(max([len(a), len(b), len(c)]))
print(min([len(a), len(b), len(c)]))
```

The answer to this was 4, 2.
Can someone explain why?

Comment: Because thats the smallest and largest array lengths?..

Comment: Which bit of the code confuses you?

Comment: Max means maximum value, where you are comparing with the size of the list.
min means minimum value, where you are comparing with the size of the list.

Comment: if you want the max for each list you can use sth like this: `[max(l) for l in [a,b,c]]` which outputs: `[8, 10, 200]`

Comment: `len(a)=3`, `len(b)=4`, `len(c)=2`. `max([len(a),len(b),len(c)])` is same as `max([3,4,2])` which returns highest element i.e. `4`. Similarly for `min` also.

Answer (score 2):

In the code you've shared, there are 3 built-in functions being used:

[`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

> **max(arg1, arg2, *args[, key])**
>
> Return the largest item in an iterable
>   or the largest of two or more arguments.

[`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)

> **min(arg1, arg2, *args[, key])**
>
> Return the smallest item in an iterable
>   or the smallest of two or more arguments.

[`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)

> **len(s)**
>
> Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The
>   argument may be a sequence (such as a string, bytes, tuple, list, or
>   range) or a collection (such as a dictionary, set, or frozen set).

In your example now

```
len(a) = 3
len(b) = 4
len(c) = 2
```

Therefore,

the maximum value of `max([len(a), len(b), len(c)])` is `4` and the minimum value `min([len(a), len(b), len(c)])` is `2`